# We need more Questions!

Tags: discussion

So, I've been looking at the stats on area51 for Blender Stack Exchange and most of them are looking pretty good... other than questions per day. When the site originally started, there was a pretty steady amount of questions(about 20 per day!). Since then, the stats have been slipping and we've come to a new low of 7 questions per day. We have more users(since we went public), but we haven't had too many more questions. Does anyone know of any websites or social media categories/groups where Blender.SE can be advertised to beginner users?

Comment: This is only natural, other beta sites I have been on took the same turn right out of private beta. Give it time.. http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89/how-do-we-promote-our-site We have exhausted pretty much most of what is in our power, the best we can get now is a feature from BN.

Comment: I'm noticing a trend that people will vote for answers of questions but not necessarily the question, I can imagine this acts as a disincentive to put much effort into asking questions that you already know the answer to. Unless you are also answering your own question.. There's still a lot of low hanging fruit, I suspect we will see sporadic efforts .

Comment: Carefully advertise it as a Q&A though, not as a forum. Increased traffic and a rise in the number of questions is great, if those don't end up closed because the site is misunderstood. As @iKlsR says though, I wouldn't worry too much at this point.

Comment: Can we answer the questions with more questions to raise the question count? (Seriously though, I think given enough time, this will resolve itself. For a beta, it's growing fine)

Comment: @MikePan, yeah, we're really growing now. I asked this question when we were down to two questions a day and less than 400 views.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Added this now as [blender.org](http://www.blender.org) frontpage news item, and on our main [education/help](http://www.blender.org/education-help/) page.

Thanks for all the work so far, it's very promising!

Answer (score 5):

Most sites will start in private beta with 20-50-ish questions per day (QPD). After private beta ends, the QPD stat normally falls below 5, sometimes as low as 1 or 2. After that it will plateau a while and eventually start rising again.

This is all part a normal beta's growth. Don't upset yourself too much about those numbers on the Area 51 page. They'll improve when the community grows and the best way too gather a larger community is to keep the quality high. Publicity is important, but without quality we won't go anywhere.

Comment: +1 for the note about quality.